# How do I generate dependency tree only for the specific module in a multi module project - MAVEN

Tags: maven, multi-module, dependency-tree

I have multi-module project.
say for example :
x
|_b
|_c
When I run the command
mvn dependency : tree
This will output dependency trees for the modules "b" and "c"

I know we can get specific module dependency tree by using this command
mvn -f modulename/pom.xml dependency:tree

Is there a way to generate a dependency tree for specific module using only its groupId,artifactId, and version.

Answer (score 6):

What about

`mvn dependency:tree -pl modulename`

?

This should run the command only on the desired module.